# What's the equivalent of ruby print + $stdout.flush in elixir

Tags: ruby, elixir, stdout

I can't find how to refresh a single line of output with Elixir.

In Ruby we can do this :

```
n = 0
loop do
  print n
  $stdout.flush
  n += 1
end
```

But what should I use to do the same with Elixir ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `IO.write/1`. There's no need to manually flush stdout as far as I can see. The following code writes 1 to 10 in a single line with a 1 second delay between each number. stdout is flushed automatically after each write.

```
for i <- 1..10 do
  IO.write i
  :timer.sleep(1000)
end
```

Output:

```
12345678910
```

(With a 1 second delay between each number.)

Comment: Sleeping is not the same as IO flush. IO does automatically get flushed eventually, but Elixir has no built-in way to flush when writing to :stdio or :stderr, as far as I can tell. A  race condition occurs when writing to both: `fn -> IO.puts(:stderr, "foo"); IO.puts("bar"); end.()`. Here, "foo" and "bar" will be printed in a random order. Flushing IO would prevent this from occurring. StringIO does have a flush, but that cannot be used with :stdio to my knowledge